# How to search separated by comma value in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Need help in cakephp

I have a field `furnished_details` in a table and its content is below value (separated by comma). eg .

> Double Bed,Flat TV : small (19"),Mirror,Extra storage,Window AC,Ceiling Fan,Lamp,Chair,Armoire,Mini-Fridge

Now in advanced search after submitting form, I store array value in a string separated by commas. eg .

> TV,Bed,Linens Provided,Window AC,Ceiling Fan,Lamp,Chair,Armoire,Desk,Night stand,Extra storage

I just use

```
$conditions[]=array("MATCH(Room.furnished_details) AGAINST('$ame' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" );
```

but I don't get actual result .

Comment: $conditions[]=array("MATCH(Room.furnished_details) AGAINST('$ame' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" );

thats worrking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for several words (that are comma separated) inside a database field that contains other words that are comma separated? If I get it right, it's bound to get ugly.

The only way I can think of is to take your string, explode(',', $string), and then loop on this array to build a LIKE statement for each of your word.

I really advise to change your database structure though, why do you have a comma separated field for something that looks (to me) as if it should be a separate table altogether?

Comment: hi PoloRM .....


>$conditions[]=array("MATCH(Room.furnished_details) AGAINST('$ame' IN BOOLEAN MODE)" );


thats working properly ...  :) thanks for your advice and thanks to air4x  Edit my post  :)